# Adding my own page to a subtext application

Tags: asp.net, subtext

I've just installed subtext and am intending on hosting on discountasp.net. I want to add my own pages to the application (just 3) but if I add a standard aspx I get a 404. I'd ideally like to have a masterpage that uses some of the list controls in subtext so I can keep a list of Recent Posts and Archive on the side bar. It's an ideal, otherwise I could create a couple of my own controls to drop into the page to replicate IF that's not possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note: This applies to Subtext 2.1.2 and below**

You'll need to add a handler mapping in web.config. Subtext tries to handle *all* requests.

The easiest thing to do is to create a directory where you want all your custom pages to live and map a PageHandlerFactory for that directory.

For example, search for the following in web.config

```
<add verb="*" path="HostAdmin/*.aspx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory"/>
```

And add the following line after

```
<add verb="*" path="custompages/*.aspx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory"/>
```

In the upcoming Subtext 2.5, you won't need to do this. You can simply drop your page anywhere in a directory and it'll just work.